# Is there a more effective way to import JSON into a Pandas Data Frame than my currently outlined method?

Tags: python, json, pandas, pycharm

Wanted to see if anyone had any insight on this.

For a side project and for Python practice, I'm loading my fantasy football draft data into PyCharm. I'm doing this by using Postman to GET the league data from the Sleeper API as a JSON file, and then I am loading the JSON files into PyCharm as dictionaries and converting them to data frames using pd.DataFrame.from_dict for about 30 leagues. I'll then concat them all into a master dataframe for analysis.

Long story short; Is this the most effective way to do this? I'm very new to JSON and my Python is rusty as heck right now. I intend to use the data frames for general trend analysis. I'd appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Try `pd.json_normalize`

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation and this definitely looks like an interesting lead. Thank you!

Comment: you could use Python `requests` to get data from `Sleeper API`

Comment: try https://github.com/amirziai/flatten

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, I work for the sports betting media company The Action Network. One of our API's returns some json so I will use that since you did not provide the postman request. Below is a simple example of how a list of json can be easily converted into a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.actionnetwork.com/web/v1/scoreboard/nfl')
j = r.json()
games = j['games']
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(games)
```